# How to deploy Angular to the Web

Tags: angular

Most of the angular tutorials I have found by googling require installing node, CLI, and npm. But to deploy a program to the Web one needs a call to the ng-app and a link to the angular library. I can't install node or npm on my hosting provider so how do I deploy the programs to the Web? What are the tutorials missing?

Comment: You'll not be able to install angular so you won't be able to host an agular application.

Comment: The issue is with your host if they don't allow you to install the required components. Either contact them so they can do the install for you or find a better hosting provider.

Comment: Node may be required during the development process but it is absolutely not required for running the application. An angular application is just a collection of static HTML, CSS, and JS. Any hosting solution that can run a website with HTML, CSS, and JS can run an angular application. Just as you would add those resources for a non-angular website, you can similarly upload the built/bundled angular files to the host for serving.

Comment: In Angular documentation you can find more information about deployment and how to configure server to always return index.html (necessary for routing)
https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy an app by commands, but that is not necessary.

Build your app in your local environment by command like `ng build --prod`. Then you have the build directory named `dist/` unless you set the `--outputPath` option.

After that, you just upload the build to host server. But server might need some configurations.

You can get more information about deployment on Angular official document. https://angular.io/guide/deployment